# Intermittent Bad Gateway nginx (with Django)

Tags: django, nginx, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm using vagrant and virtualbox for my Django environment. The django environment uses nginx. Everything works fine except intermittently I'll see 502 bad gateway errors. When these errors happen, there is nothing in nginx `access.log` or `error.log`. Here are my configurations

Vagrant file private network

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host 192.168.33.10;
    proxy_set_header X-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to debug or fix this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the Django development server? Do you see anything in the console?

Comment: Yes, I am running django `python manage.py runserver`. No, there is nothing in the dev server Stdout when the 502 happens. Its like the request never even reached Django server.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but using the proxy_pass together with development server is not suitable for production and it is hard to debug such a configuration. It is not difficult to configure something like NginX with uWSGI or Gunicorn.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `python manage.py runserver 192.168.33.10:8000` since Django defaults your ip to `127.0.0.1` and nginx might have problems with that.